# Center control programatically

Tags: javascript, godot

Is there a convenient way to center a node, or more specifically, a TextureRect, into the screen? Note in my case my display window is set to be stretched in 2D "keep" aspect.

Obviously the position could be calculated with the formula:

```
x = WindowWidth / 2 + TextureWidth / 2
y = WindowHeight / 2 + TextureHeight / 2
```

But I've not found how to get the original window size of the Godot project. I'm obtaining the screen width through `this.get_tree().root.size.x`, and it varies according to how the window is resized. For example, my project width is 1024 and I'd like to not express this width in my code. Is that possible?

Godot Engine also seems to have the notion of anchor and centering when you use its visual editor, so I suspect there is a way of centering the node without manual calculus.

##### Update

The answer by @Theraot shows method of positioning node to center based on a preset, but it positions the node elsewhere, not on the center:

(Note "state" means "scene")

```js
import State from '../State.jsx';
import RecoyxLogo from 'res://img/company-logo/recoyx.png';

export default class PresentsState extends State {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async _ready() {
        await godot.yield(this.get_tree(), 'idle_frame');
        let recoyxLogo = new godot.TextureRect;
        recoyxLogo.texture = RecoyxLogo;
        recoyxLogo.expand = true;
        recoyxLogo.rect_size = new godot.Vector2(1200 / 2, 600 / 2);
        // recoyxLogo.rect_position = new godot.Vector2(this.get_tree().root.size.x / 2 + (1200 / 2 / 2), this.get_tree().root.size.y / 2 + (600 / 2) / 2);
        recoyxLogo.set_anchors_and_margins_preset(godot.Control.PRESET_CENTER);
        this.add_child(recoyxLogo);
    }

    _process(delta) {
    }
}
```

Here's `State.jsx`:

```js
export default class State extends godot.Node2D {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // this.scale = new godot.Vector2(0.47, 0.47);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of your control from code by setting its `rect_size` and `rect_position`.

And you can do that in a method connected to the `"resized"` signal of the root of the scene tree (the root of the scene is a `Viewport`, and - as you would expect - it emits the `"resized"` every time its size changes).

As per the original window size, you can read it from project settings, by calling `ProjectSettings.get_setting` passing the property path as parameter. The properties for the window size are `"display/window/size/width"` and `"display/window/size/height"` (you can figure out these by looking in the Project Settings window or on the documentation for `ProjectSettings`).

And yes, you can set margins (with the method `set_margin`) and anchors (with the method `set_anchor`) from code, and also use the presets (with the methods `set_margins_preset`, `set_anchors_preset`, and `set_anchors_and_margins_preset` - this last method is a convenient way to set both at the same time). Setting the preset `Control.PRESET_CENTER` should do.

Comment: Interesting, I'm trying to set anchors/margins preset to center to a node, but it puts the node far away from the center. I didn't scale any of the parent nodes. My node to be centered has only one parent node; I did try scaling the root node to be smaller than 1 but it continues far away from the destination. Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: @Klaider Is the parent node set to fill the screen? I think it is centering to the parent node, but the parent node is not centered.

Comment: I've exposed my root node in the question, which is a scene (or what is called "state"), it seems there is no way to tell it to fill the screen, according to the API docs ([Node2D](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node2d.html)).

Comment: @Klaider I see. Yes, that is a problem. The `Node2D` does not have any size Godot uses for centering things inside. Does making it a `Control` work for you? Otherwise you will have to center using `set_global_position`.

Comment: I tried to make State inherit `godot.Control` and then `godot.TextureRect` (setting rect_size to the project screen resolution), both failed :(